# I'm unable to reshape a 1D np array of np arrays of size 3 without modifying them

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
rgb_list = []

int_list = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

for num in range(0, len(int_list)-3, 3):
    rgb_list.append(received_int[num:num+3])

received_array = np.array(rgb_list)
print(received_array)

received_array_2d = np.ndarray.reshape(received_array, (5, 2))
print(received_array_2d)
```

So up until received_array, everything was fine, but when I try to reshape it into a 2D array, I get an error code, I assume it's because numpy is considering each integer individually, not the arrays.

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 30 into shape (5,2)
```

the output of `print(received_array)` is

```
[[1 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 1 1]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]
 [1 0 1]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 1 1]]
```

I want to get a 2D array that resembles this

```
[[1 0 0] [1 0 0] [1 1 0] [1 0 0] [1 1 1]
 [0 0 1] [0 1 0] [1 0 1] [0 1 0] [0 1 1]]
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: This is not a reproducible example. You do not define `received_int` anywhere.

Comment: shape = (5,2,3)?

Comment: @mozway This does not seem to be about splitting a list but about how numpy arrays work.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I see, sorry, I'll reopen

Comment: Why do you want a numpy array containing arrays instead of a 2-dimensional array?

Comment: The output is not fully clear, I assume 3 dimensions given the format…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using numpy arrays, use numpy methods: `reshape` is appropriate here.

You first need to trim your array to a multiple of the expected dimensions:

```
int_list = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
X,Y,Z = 2,5,3
int_list[:X*Y*Z].reshape((2,5,3))
```

output:

```
array([[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]],
       [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]],
      ])
```

Comment: Yup that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!
Should I delete my question? It isn't well formulated, and I should've thought about it :(